# How can you add and play a video on fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, video, fragment

I am a new developer, trying to get my head around android. I managed to get fragments working and I am unable to add and play a video on it.

Also, I added a image successfully, is it possible to pinch zoom on that image, if so how?

I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this library 
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView  for zoom on image.
 if you read the Sample Usage and analyse the sample app you can zoom it.

About  playing video on fragment. It is simple just google it.